# jquery ajax - maintain ajax call sequence

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, svg

**I know my questions is marked as duplicate. But the given answer is using `async:false`. I don't want to force synchronous requests. How do maintain async ajax call sequence ???**

**I don't need to replace the content. I need to append `svg` one after another in a sequence.**

I am appending 5 `svg` elements in a `div`. All svgs are coming by `ajax` call. The issue is the order of those svgs. Every time they appended in different order. I want to maintain their order. Please find below my code:

```
    FlagRow.DEFAULTS = {
                flagOrder: [
                        Enums.flagType.INDIA,
                        Enums.flagType.USA,
                        Enums.flagType.UK,
                        Enums.flagType.FRANCE,
                        Enums.flagType.GERMANY
                ]
            }
var container = $(document.createElement("div"));
    var topic = new Array();
            for (var key in this.options.flagOrder) {
                topic.push(this.options.flagOrder[key]);            
            } 

    var appendFlag = function (flag) {
                console.log(flag);
                var svgDiv = $(document.createElement("div"));
                $(svgDiv).addClass('svgDiv');

                var importedSVGRootElement = document.importNode(flag.documentElement, true);
                $(importedSVGRootElement).attr('viewBox', '0 0 100 125');

                svgDiv.append(importedSVGRootElement)
                container.append(svgDiv);                
            } 

    $.each(topic, function (i, val) {            
                $.when(//ajax call to get flag svg).done(function (flag ) { appendFlag(flag ); });
    });



     // api call to get flag svg
    var deferred = $.Deferred();
        $.ajax({
                        url: url,
                        type: 'get',
                        data: '',
                        dataType: 'xml',
                        timeout: 300000,
                        success: function (data) {                        
                            deferred.resolve(data);
                        },
                        error: function (e) {
                            console.log(':::error in flag:::', e);
                        },
                        beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                            xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", 'myapikey');                        
                        }
                    });
```

Here every time flag svg comes in different order. I want it to display it in an order of `enum`. And so I tried it with `$.when().done()`. But it's working as per my requirement.

**How do I maintain order of appended svgs coming via ajax call ???**

Comment: I don't need to replace the content. I need to append svgs one after another.

Comment: Reread the duplicate. It is exactly the problem the duplicate is trying to solve.

Comment: I don't want to force synchronous ajax calls by async:false.

Comment: Well, they are not in a defined order **because** they are asynchronous

Answer (score 1):

You can use `async: false` to mimic what you tried to do with Deferred. Since you know the order at the moment of calling your ajax requests, using placeholders as [the duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10098890/how-to-make-multiple-ajax-requests-in-a-loop-return-values-sequentially?lq=1) (for some reason they re-opened this...) suggests is your best bet.

```
function getAllTheFlags() {
  for( var i = 0; i < 5; i++ ) {
    insertPlaceHolder( i ); //inserts <div id="placeholder-i"></div> at desired location
    insertFlag( i );
  }
}

function insertFlag( i ) {
  $.ajax( { ... } ).success( function( data ) {
    var svgDiv = $(document.createElement("div"));
    $(svgDiv).addClass('svgDiv');

    var importedSVGRootElement = document.importNode(flag.documentElement, true);
    $(importedSVGRootElement).attr('viewBox', '0 0 100 125');
    svgDiv.append(importedSVGRootElement)

    $( '#placeholder-' + i ).replaceWith( svgDiv );
  } );
}
```

The function `insertFlag(..)` is mandatory, as you need to copy the value of i.

Answer (score 0):

You can not expect async ajax call to end in order of call. But you could wrap it in a function that takes the element as parameter that you can acces in your ajax callback.

```
function fetchContent(element, url){

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        success: function(data) {
            element.whatever(...); 
        }
    });
}
```

In your code you then create a div or search for an existent one. And call your fetchContent by passing that element as a parameter. Even if your ajax calls don't end in the order of call the content should be added to the good element.

I think it should work.